# Couch DB Installation Centos

Tags: centos, couchdb, firewall, centos7

We have installed couchdb on Centos 7 and we are  having issues connecting to it from the internal IP address or public IP address on an Amazon Centos Image.    This message I am getting:

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to <public_ip>:5984; Connection refused
curl: (7) Failed connect to <internal_ip>:5984; Connection refused
```

But if I hit it locally it will work no problem:

```
curl 0.0.0.0:5984
Response:  {"couchdb":"Welcome","uuid":"b320fd3c83007007ce2a620ef8930df4","version":"1.6.1","vendor":{"name":"The Apache Software Foundation","version":"1.6.1"}}
```

So I'm confident it's either a network issue or firewall issue.

This is what I did:
Centos 7  (AMI:   ami-96a818fe)

Installed erlang and couchdb

```
yum update
```

Setup a firewall:

```
sudo yum install firewalld
sudo systemctl enable firewalld
sudo systemctl start firewalld

sudo firewall-cmd --get-active-zones   (made sure we have public available)
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=ssh
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=5984/tcp
```

Implement changes:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Made sure it's all there:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --list-all
```

Created a security group opened to the world:

```
Type    Protocol    Port Range  Source
All TCP TCP 0 - 65535   0.0.0.0/0
```

Anything else I am missing?   Seems like Amazon is all set but why can't I hit this machine from the public IP for this port or internal IP on the machine for this port?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `--add-*` commands are not taking immediate effect, due to the `--perm` options. The `--reload` may not pull in permanent changes. Try this again without `--perm` and see if the port actually opens:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5984/tcp
```

You usually want to experiment with commands like that, and then only add `--permanent` once you know they’re working as intended.

Comment: @SoccerCoach71 Were you able to get this working? Please update if you had trouble, or accept so others will see it as a useful approach.